# Opportunity Layout Does in a Record Type is not Updating automatically on existing Opportunities

Tags: opportunity, custom-field, picklist, page-layout, record-type

I have two record types for Opportunities,  Record Type 1 utilizing Layout 1 and Record Type 2 utilizing Layout 2. Historically when a Layout update is made to Layout 1 (say a field is added), the change is updated and included in that Record Type on all existing Opportunities using Layout 1. All I do is go to Opportunity Layouts, choose Layout 1 and add that field, click save.

When I update Layout 2 the same way, and add another value to a picklist to be used in Layout 2, that Picklist does not get updated in Record Type 2 Opportunities utilizing Layout 2. I have to delete the record type and reassign it to the layout that has includes this updated picklist every single time. Is there any reason why the field wouldn't just automatically update on Record Type 2 utilizing Layout 2?

Thank you for any help in advance. Please let me know if any screen caps or other information is necessary.

Comment: Did your click into the record type and the click edit next to the picklist field to add the new value to the list of available values?

Comment: I don't think this is related to the layout tbh. Did you add the new picklist value to be available for your record type 2?

Comment: @LievenJuwet Where is there an option to add the updated picklist (not new, just one more item was added to it) to record type 2?

Comment: One more thing happens that is weird. When I activate an Opportunity Record Type for the first time, that Opportunity Record Type shows up when creating a new opportunity. But if I deactivate and then reactivate this same Opportunity Record Type, it doesn't show up when a new Opportunity is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment my guess is that the picklist value is not added for your record type 2 and that it is not related to any issue with layouts.

To validate this assumption you can check the following:

To check existing picklist values:

Go to the record type definition, for example:

My record type for account
[image]

Go to the record type details
[image]

Here there is a list of available picklists

Click edit to validate which values are available for the record type:
[image]

When adding new picklist values there is always an option on the bottom that allows you to set for which recordtypes the value applies. By default none is selected I believe, this might be the issue.

Comment: How would I add more pick lists to be available for editing in this Record Type?

Comment: Never mind, this is simpler than I thought, the pick list field was indeed included.